# CSAPP invalid implementation of function cread

Tags: c

I am a reader of your great book CSAPP 2e. I've a question regarding chapter 3.6.6.

In this chapter the author used a function called cread to show that in some situation we should not use conditional moves.

function `cread()` is as follows:

```
int cread(int* xp) {
    return (xp? *xp : 0);
}
```

The assembly code of this function is :

```
1 movl     $0   , %eax                     Set 0 as return value
2 testl    %edx , %edx                     Test xp
3 cmovne  (%edx), %eax                     if !0, dereference xp to get return value
```

The author emphasized the problem is that the dereference of `xp` is invalid if `xp` is null. But as I see it, line 1 is for the condition that `xp` is a null pointer, and in line 3, if `xp` is null, `(%edx)` will not be copied to `%eax`, so this code has avoided the possibility of dereferencing a null pointer.

Additionally, when I looked this problem in CSAPP 3e, the assembly code of this function has changed as follows :

```
1 cread:
2 movq    (%rdi), %rax        
3 tests    %rdi , %rdi
4 move     $0   , %edx
5 cmove    %rdx , %rax
6 ret
```

I can see the problem in the second assembly code that in line 2, if `xp` is null pointer then this dereference is an error. However, I cannot figure out if there's same error in the first piece of assembly code (actually I think this piece of code is correct).

My question is: Is my understanding correct, or is there really an error in the first piece of assembly code?

Answer (score 1):

In the third instruction:

```
cmovne  (%edx), %eax
```

it will first get the value of (%edx), then analyze the condition, and finally move (%edx) to %eax or not according to the condition.
So even if %edx=0, it will still access the value of (%edx), which will cause segmentation fault.